# Attribute validation for entity properties that are nonrequired such as Email and Url, Is this possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am attempting to add validation attributes to my entity properties like so. :

```
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 1 to 100 characters")]
[EmailAddress]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

What I am running into is the fact that these properties are not required, but it still applies the attribute validation, and returns email address is invalid, specifically when this non required field is empty.

Is there any way to use these [Email] and [Url] when the property is not required and empty?

I am assuming there is, but have been unable to find anything on this.

Comment: how about using the `DataTypeAttribute` instead? (`[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]`)

Comment: Thought that would work, but it does not.

Comment: I did the same and it didn't validate empty email addresses. Could you add the view code? Also, validation fires in client or server side?

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work. Do you have the `[Required]` attribute on the model's property (assuming this is a view model)?

Comment: It is a nonrequired field, but I still want to use the [EmailAddress] for when this field is present.

Comment: I understand. The code you provided does exactly what you want. I set up a project with the same annotations and it worked as expected.

Comment: Can't believe I left out of the question, this specific scenario is for when the field itself is empty and nonrequired.  The attribute is being applied.

Comment: @UserSmith That's the scenario I tested. In my test the EmailAddress attribute was only validated if I entered text in the field. If I left it blank it did not trigger validation. In your scenario, is the validation occurring on client or server side?

Comment: Technically server side, because it has to grab the entity attributes in order to perform the validation.  I am not using jquery to do the validation.  On my team there are probably 3 others having this same issue we have just done our own regexs in order to bypass this, but I can't seem to get past the idea that this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Value for Email,if Email field was empty return value to model:`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Email,new{Value=""})
```